# When plotting month wise data in Line chart, I get extra ticks in x_axis, but when I plot in Bar chart it's fine, why so?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, charts

When plotting month wise data in Line chart, I get extra ticks in x_axis, but when I plot in Bar chart it's fine. Now how to eliminate the extra ticks for Line Chart?

```
df.plot(legend=False)
```

[image]

when I plot the same in bar chart, its fine:

```
df.plot.bar(legend=False)
```

[image]

Now, how to get rid of the extra ticks(float values) in x_axis for Line chart?

PS:

```
df['month'].unique()
```

gives

```
array([ 7,  8,  9, 10], dtype=int64)
```

as Output.

Comment: Try using `plt.xticks(df['month'].unique())` OR ``plt.xticks([7,8,9,10])``. The answer to your question is that the line chart is a continuous plot but the bar plot is a discrete chart at specified x-values.

Comment: If you're plotting a line graph, matplotlib assumes that you have a continuous variable and so generates ticklabels to suit. You can also supply an additional argument to `xticks`. I would use  the `df["month"].unique()` as the label, and there's sometimes some experimentation to get the tick positions you need (sometimes `plot` uses values from 0, other times not)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with columns that contain `dates`, I think it would be good to work with `datetime` objects even if it requires more code.

Example:

```
  Month Value
0     7     2
1     8     1
2     9     3
3    10     1
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format='%m')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot_date(df['Month'], df['Value'], 'b-')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m'))
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]